# iOS Safari : For a overlay like a pop up menu 100vh does not work correctly and gets hidden under the 44px pixel high menu bar of safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, cross-browser

The issue is that 100vh is not correctly handled in iOS Safari. It incorrectly computes the height up to the bottom of the safari menu bar [at the bottom] and renders the pop up menu up to the lower edge of the menu bar. This results in  the menu to be hidden partially and creates problem is designing a scrollable pop up menu for cross devices using 100vh.
[details here](https://benfrain.com/the-ios-safari-menu-bar-is-hostile-to-web-apps-discuss/) | [more details here](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html)

So looking to find an alternate solution without using 100vh such that it works on all browsers and platform.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by setting the menu height to window['innerHeight'] + 'px' instead of using 100vh.

Then I update the height as the browser size changes [ pseudo code below ]

addEventListener('resize', () => menu.style.height = window['innerHeight'] + 'px');

This works fine across all browsers and mobile devices.